# ¿Puedo cambiar el formato y la extension de un archivo excel en C#?

Tags: c#, devexpress

Actualmente tengo esta fracción de código:

```
saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:/Escritorio";
saveFileDialog.Title = "Guardar Archivo en Excel";
saveFileDialog.FileName = "";
saveFileDialog.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv";
```

Pero cuando abro el archivo me dice que el formato y la extensión no coinciden, estoy trabajando con C# y DevExpress.

Agradezco todo tipo de comentarios para poder resolver el problema.

Este es el código completo:

```
private void ExceltoolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:/Escritorio";
        saveFileDialog.Title = "Guardar Archivo en Excel";
        saveFileDialog.FileName = "";
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv";

        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            Excel.Application MExcel = new Excel.Application();
            MExcel.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            for (int i = 1; i < encargadosDataGridView.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                MExcel.Cells[1, i] = encargadosDataGridView.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < encargadosDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < encargadosDataGridView.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    MExcel.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = encargadosDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            MExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(saveFileDialog.FileName.ToString());
            MExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
            MExcel.Quit();
        }
    }
```

---

Código Completo:

```
private void ExceltoolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:/Escritorio";
        saveFileDialog.Title = "Guardar Archivo en Excel";
        saveFileDialog.FileName = "";
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv";

        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            Excel.Application MExcel = new Excel.Application();
            MExcel.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            for (int i = 1; i < encargadosDataGridView.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                MExcel.Cells[1, i] = encargadosDataGridView.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < encargadosDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < encargadosDataGridView.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    MExcel.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = encargadosDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            MExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(saveFileDialog.FileName.ToString());
            MExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
            MExcel.Quit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: No olvides Joaquin, agregar ediciones mediante la opción "editar". Por otro lado realiza el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento del sitio, también [ask] que te brinda información para realizar preguntas y obtener excelentes respuestas, bienvenido al sitio, saludos!

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar cómo se ve tu archivo CSV? y recuerda que un CSV no es precisamente un archivo de Excel